# Exercise of complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$  entire function such as $f(z)=f(z+i)=f(z+1)$ for all $z$. Show that $f$ is constant.

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi Peppe, welcome to StackExchange! Can you tell us what you've tried/what you think might be the key to solving the problem so that we might help you better? Also, in the future, please use MathJax to format your questions.

Comment: Sure we can. But first of all please write what did you try.